# IDE not showing the widget end comment in flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am just starting out with flutter and normally when we code in flutter it shows a `virtual comment` text in IDE after every widget end. But now I cant see it anymore. I dont know what I did to get it away.

Before

```
void main() =>
    runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    ));//MaterialApp(These helper comments are missing now)
```

Now its showing without the virtual comments

```
void main() =>
    runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    ));
```

Here is the flutter and dart versions am now using

```
Flutter 1.5.4-hotfix.2 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7a4c33425d (4 days ago) • 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
Engine • revision 52c7a1e849
Tools • Dart 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)
```

Could some one tell me what I did wrong here and how to turn it back on in android studio?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The checkbox is in Settings (Preferences) | Editor | General | Appearance, toggle 'Show closing labels in Dart source code'. For this change to take effect, you'll have to restart your IDE.

Comment: in Android Studio search in settings for 'Show closing labels in Dart source code'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It's all about closing parenthesis ')'.
Just put ',' after every widget's closing parenthesis in order to display the comment.